# How to start activity from adapter in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a simple `Adapter`. I am trying to start `Activity` from within the `Adapter` when user clicks on an item. I am not able to get the `context` in the `onClick`. I am performing `onClick` inside `MyViewHolder` class. Here is my adapter code:

```
class LeadListAdapter(context:Context, private val leadList: List<Lead>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LeadListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    var activity:Context = context
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflatedView = parent.inflate(R.layout.custom_lead_row, false)
        return MyViewHolder(inflatedView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return leadList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindLead(leadList[position])
    }

    class MyViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
        //2
        private var view: View = v
        private var lead: Lead? = null

        //3
        init {
            v.setOnClickListener(this)
            v.trackButton.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        //4
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val intent = Intent(activity) //Getting error here
        }

        fun bindLead(lead: Lead) {
            this.lead = lead
            view.leadName.text = lead.cusName
            view.leadMobileNumber.text = lead.mobileNo.toString()
            view.loanAmount.text = lead.amount.toString()
            view.leadId.text = "Lead Id: ${lead.id.toString()}"
            view.loanType.text = lead.productType
            view.loanTypeIcon.text = getCharsFromWords(lead.productType)
        }

        private fun getCharsFromWords(productType: String?): String? {
            val words = productType!!.split(Regex("\\s+"))
            val quote: String
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (word in words) {
                sb.append(word[0].toString())
            }
            quote = sb.toString()
            return quote
        }

        companion object {
            //5
            private val LEAD_KEY = "LEAD"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unresolved reference context

**NOTE**

You should **`return`** ***Context*** object also.

```
return MyViewHolder(inflatedView,context)
```

Then

```
 class MyViewHolder(v: View,context:Context) :
```

Comment: I am getting `Unresolved reference context`. As you can see I tried using a var `activity`. But its not visible inside `MyViewHolder` class

Comment: @XoXo `val context:Context`

Comment: As you can see I tried using a `var` activity. But its not visible inside `MyViewHolder` class

Comment: As you said I did. But its saying me `Unresolved reference context` in my `onClick` method which is inside `MyViewHolder` class

Comment: @XoXo pass context then `return MyViewHolder(inflatedView,context)`

Comment: I got one more solution. I declared `MyViewHolder` class as `inner class`. That did the trick. @IntelliJ

Comment: Please add that `return MyViewHolder(inflatedView,context)` to your answer. Will mark it accepted :)

Comment: I would argue that stating a `val` initialized Object as "Immutable" is incorrect - it is read only, you can mutate a `val` Object, consider a `val` initialised class which has setter methods for internal `var` Objects, you are free to mutate the object.  Truly Immutable is initialized once and closed to change. TL: DR: `val` is equivalent of `final` keyword in Java, however its internal structure can be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error at that line because Intents are not declared like that. You need to also supply a java Class as the second parameter.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) for the correct ways of obtaining an Intent object.

**EDIT**

In regards to my comment, you need to state your ViewHolder class as a inner class. ie:

```
inner class MyViewHolder(holder: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(holder){}
```

As stated in the [Kotlin Reference Manual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html), unless modified as a inner class, nested classes will not have access to the outer class' members.

Comment: I didn't write it completely. I was getting error when I passed the first parameter i.e the context.

Comment: You were getting a syntax error. If you're using Android Studio, it complained because you didn't finish the declaration. And sure enough, if you compile it, it will  give compilation error. As mentioned, Intents cannot be declared with just a context. You need to provide the java Class of the activity the intent will be sent to.
Ensure as well, that you passed an existing object of the context when the Adapter is created.

Comment: I forgot to mention as well, you need to state your ViewHolder class as a "inner class" not just class. Otherwise, you won't be able to access members of the outer.